# Convert column value to row value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot

In SQL Server, I am trying to convert the from table 1 to table 2. From reading other answers from stack overflow, I can do some sort of `row_number()`. But the problem is I need do some inner join after the conversion because the following script use `max()` aggregate function, it kind force other fields from other tables to have some sort of aggregate function as well. So I was wondering if there is an alternative approach to solve this problem? Or if there is a way to handle this aggregate function when do join with another table.

```
select max(case when key = 'ab' then Value end) as ab, 
       max(case when key = 'cd' then Value end) as cd
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by key order by Value) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
group by seq;
```

table 1

[image]

table 2

[image]

Comment: provide some sample data of your other table and exactly what is your desired output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with this below script-

```
SELECT id,
MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'car1' THEN name END) car1,
MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'car2' THEN name END) car2, 
MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'car3' THEN name END) car3 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go for PIVOT feature.

```sql
;WITH src as
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        VALUES
        (1, 'Car1', 'nissan'),
        (1, 'Car2', 'audi'),
        (1, 'Car3', 'toyota')
    ) as t (id, name, value)
)
SELECT *
FROM src
PIVOT
(
    max(VALUE) FOR NAME IN ([Car1], [Car2], [Car3])
) as pvt
```

```
+----+--------+------+--------+
| id |  Car1  | Car2 |  Car3  |
+----+--------+------+--------+
|  1 | nissan | audi | toyota |
+----+--------+------+--------+
```